# Query data from three tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2005

I have 3 tables called `tbl_monday`, `tbl_tuesday` and `tbl_wednesday` that consist of data as follows:

**tbl_monday**

```
id    empid   Plan
---------------------
1     6       Mon_27
2     6       Mon_27
3     6       Mon_27
```

**tbl_tuesday**

```
id    empid   Plan
--------------------
1     6       Tue_28
2     6       Tue_28
3     6       Tue_28
```

**tbl_wenesday**

```
id  empid     Plan
------------------
1     6       Wed_29
2     6       Wed_29
3     6       Wed_29
```

Is there any easy way to get result like this?

```
empid    Plan
----------------------
6       Mon_27
6       Tue_28
6       Wed_29
```

Comment: Can you please give context as to what these tables mean in relation to eachother and how this data is used? It really does seem like poor design as is, and the most appropriate answer cant be known without more context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could query using `union` between the three tables, which would provide the unique results from all the queries:

```
SELECT empid, [plan] FROM tbl_monday
UNION
SELECT empid, [plan] FROM tbl_tuesday
UNION
SELECT empid, [plan] FROM tbl_wednesday
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/912c1/2)**

Comment: @ZoharPeled you are wrong.  As I noted above, the `union` operator (unlike `union all`) provides unique results - not just between queries, but altogether. See the SQLFiddle I added to my answer for proof.

Answer (score 1):

The easy was is using `union all`:

```
select *
from
(
    select top 1 empid, plan
    from tbl_monday
    order by id
) m

union all

select *
from
(
    select top 1 empid, plan
    from tbl_tuesday
    order by id
) t

union all

select *
from
(
    select top 1 empid, plan
    from tbl_Wednesday 
    order by id
) w
```

Though it does seem like you should reconsider your database design.

Comment: actually am new to database designing, that's why it seems to be a bad one.

Comment: how can i normalize this one ?